# Files created read only or read write depending on context. Why?

Tags: c#, windows, file, jenkins

A test in C# calls a dll which calls a line command tool (GDAL). On a developer workstation (windows 7) from within Visual Studio the tool creates read write files, files can be deleted at the end of the test.

But on a continuous integration station (jenkins on windows server 2012) the same files are created read only (the same code is executed).

Why is the behaviour different ? How to get the same behaviour ?

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you mean by _read only_. Is the __read-only attribute__ set on the files on the CI server? I doubt it. However, if the files are created by one user account on the CI server while another user account tries to delete them without having the necessary permissions then they cannot be deleted. Or even more sinister: the default permissions for files created during the test does not allow the __CREATOR OWNER__ to delete them. In any case it is probably a permission issue and you should examine the permissions on the _read only_ files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The files are created read only. It is possible to change this attribute and then delete them. But I don't understand why. It is the same suer which creates the file and tries to delete it.